# How to select columns in a dataframe, and skip over columns that don't exist - using data.table syntax

Tags: r, select, data.table, tidyverse

I am trying to find the data.table equivalent of `select(one_of(...))`, where a select statement is passed and if some columns do not exist in the data.table, they are skipped, instead of producing an error and failing.

The current method I know of selecting columns using data.table syntax would be `df[, ..select_cols]`, where `select_cols` is a character vector containing the names of the columns I want to select. However, this method leads to an error message when one of the column names does not exist in the data.table.

Any advice on a data.table statement that would just skip columns that don't exist in the data.table would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to keep the columns which are available in data.table.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)

select_cols <- function(dt, cols) {
  cols <- intersect(names(dt), cols)
  dt[, ..cols]
}

select_cols(dt, c('a', 'b'))

#   a b
#1: 1 2
#2: 2 3
#3: 3 4
#4: 4 5
#5: 5 6

select_cols(dt, c('a', 'c'))
#   a
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
#5: 5
```